# Whitespace in AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm getting white space in my console log from my response with AJAX. The responds I need to get is:"[1,4,6,12]" instead I'm getting: "[1,4,6,12] ".
I've tried everything... Deleting every PHP close tag, using the trim function(in PHP and JS)...

My PHP code(part not all):

```
$errors = array();

if (empty($stringUsername)) {
    $errors[] = 0;
    $bolean = true;
}
if (strlen($stringUsername) < 3 || strlen($stringUsername) > 16) {
    $errors[] = 1;
    $bolean = true;
}
if (!ctype_alnum($stringUsername)) {
    $errors[] = 2;
    $bolean = true;
}

if (empty($stringPassword)) {
    $errors[] = 3;
    $bolean = true;
}
if (strlen($stringPassword) < 6 || strlen($stringPassword) > 16) {
    $errors[] = 4;
    $bolean = true;
}

if (empty($stringPassword2)) {
    $errors[] = 5;
    $bolean = true;
}
if ($stringPassword != $stringPassword2) {
    $errors[] = 6;
    $bolean = true;
}

if (empty($stringEmail)) {
    $errors[] = 7;
    $bolean = true;
}
if (!filter_var($stringEmail, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    $errors[] = 8;
    $bolean = true;
}

if ($intMatchu != 0) {
    $errors[] = 9;
    $bolean = true;
}
if ($intMatchu != 0) {
    $errors[] = 10;
    $bolean = true;
}

if (empty($stringTerms)) {
    $errors[] = 11;
    $bolean = true;
}
if ($stringTerms == 'avok') {
    $errors[] = 12;
    $bolean = true;
}

if ($bolean == false) {
    $errors[] = 100;
}
echo json_encode($errors);
```

My JS/AJAX part(not all):

```
if (username.val() != '' && password.val() != '' && password2.val() != '' && email.val() != '' && terms.val != '') {
    var UrlToPass = 'action=aanmelden&username=' + username.val() + '&password=' + password.val() + '&password2=' + password2.val() + '&email=' + email.val() + '&av=' + terms.val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: UrlToPass,
        url: '/outgame/register.php',
        success: function (responseText) {
            if (responseText == 0) {
                $.notify('U hebt geen gebruikersnaam opgegeven!', 'error');
            } else if (responseText == 1) {
                $.notify('Uw gebruikersnaam moet meer dan 3 en minder dan 16 karakters bevatten!', 'error');
            } else if (responseText == 2) {
                $.notify('Uw gebruikersnaam bevat ongeldige tekens!', 'error');
            } else if (responseText == 3) {
                $.notify('U hebt geen wachtwoord opgegeven!', 'error');
            } else if (responseText == 4) {
                $.notify('Uw wachtwoord moet meer dan 6 en minder dan 16 karakters bevatten!', 'error');
            } else if (responseText == 5) {
                $.notify('U hebt geen tweede wachtwoord opgegeven!', 'error');
            } else if (responseText == 6) {
                $.notify('De wachtwoorden komen niet met elkaar overeen!', 'error');
            } else if (responseText == 7) {
                $.notify('U hebt geen mail adres opgegeven!', 'error');
            } else if (responseText == 8) {
                $.notify('Uw mail adres is niet geldig!', 'error');
            } else if (responseText == 9) {
                $.notify('Uw gebruikersnaam is al ingebruik!', 'error');
            } else if (responseText == 10) {
                $.notify('Er is al een account aagemaakt met dit email adres!', 'error');
            } else if (responseText == 11) {
                $.notify('U hebt onze AV niet geaccepteerd!', 'error');
            } else if (responseText == 12) {
                $.notify('Uw invoer voor onze AV is ongeldig!', 'error');
            } else if (responseText == 100) {
                $.notify('U bent succesvol geregistreerd', 'success');
            } else {
                alert('error!');
            }
            console.log(responseText);
        }
```

Thank you in advance! I'm sorry for my grammar or spelling mistakes, English isn't my mother tongue :-)

Comment: Err ... ... I'm not sure I understand the trouble.  The extra space shouldn't affect a downstream JSON Parser ... are you getting an error message somewhere?

Comment: I don't understand your problem, but if you need to remove the extra space in js do this:

responseText.replace(" ", "")

Comment: @g.d.d.c Thank you for responding! None of my if/else ifs are giving a respond. Only my else gives an responds, it gives back that it go no response... Sorry that I'm unclear, don't know how to explain it.

Comment: How does your response look like in the success call back. What is the dataType ?

Comment: @Morrisda Thank you for your respond! Can you give an example in my situation?

Comment: @bn00d I've put it on Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/hP4S28t8

Comment: `header('Content-Type: application/json');` u should place this before your echo

Comment: If you are expecting JSON string response, then why are you testing the responseText against numbers? `"[1,2,3,4,5,6]"` will never equal 1 or 2 or 3 etc

Comment: @DarkBee It still gives me white space, but the responds seems different but there's really no difference. Thank you for responding!

Comment: @PatrickEvans Do I need to echo all the lose numbers? Like this: http://pastebin.com/C9T51Vy7? Thank you for your hulp!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z2h83jh3/

Comment: Thank you for reacting @DarkBee. One question, how can I get $errors into var response = $errors? Because responseText has the value of the array of $errors.

Comment: If u leave the headers with the JSON part before your echo then jquery will parse your var `responseText` to an array. see : `console.log(responseText);`. This way u'll know what is returned datawise

Comment: @DarkBee I've done what you said, header(...'json') is now in my headers but it's still a array?

Comment: @DarkBee Finally fixed it after some research, mainly because of you and g.d.d.c :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're echoing a JSON Encoded Array, then attempting to compare it to integer values.  That's never going to work.  Response is a String when you use `$.ajax` so you need to parse it into a JSON Value via something like this:

```
$.parseJSON("[1,2,3,4] ")  // Returns [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Once you have a valid Array in JavaScript you want to see if your error codes are in that array, something like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].indexOf(3) // returns 2
```

While an error that was not present would look like this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4].indexOf(5) // returns -1
```

Comment: You could also just set `dataType` to `json` or set the content type header so jquery will do auto type checking

Comment: Do I need to do $.parseJSON(responseText); in order to get it work? Or how do I change it into a JS array? @g.d.d.c Thank you for your hulp! :-)